# Hypernym for bills, expenses, salaries, other incomes, etc

Tags: hypernyms

I'm building a budgeting database application/program and I'm looking for two words as names of tables or variables in it.  This question seeks one of them:

It encompasses the following:  I have bills & expenses, and I have sources of income. I'm looking for a hypernym that encompasses all those.

To clarify, there are things I'm **not** looking for:

a. There are questions here already on english.stackexchange that ask for a hypernym for income/expense or debit/credit but the answers all seem to refer to the transaction (the event of transferring money).  I'm distinctly not looking for a word for that (the word transaction covers that I believe).

b. One might think of a word like "entity" that might refer to the company AT&T that I pay the phone bill to, and Apple, that I pay my iCloud subscription to each month.  But maybe I also pay Apple for my Apple Music subscription each month.  Those last two are two different items.  So I'm not looking for a name for the companies or other entities I'm making the payments to.

I get a monthly bill from AT&T for the phone.  I get a monthly bill from Apple for Apple Music, and another monthly bill from Apple for my iCloud subscription.  Those are **three** records in this table (even though two are from the same company).  If I was only looking at outgoings I might call this table Bills, but I'm looking for a hypernym that would encompass those and incomes as well: eg. two other records in this table might be 'salary from my job', and 'rent paid to me for a property I rent out'.

Edit/update:  As Roger Sinasohn pointed out in the comments: yes, I'm looking for a countable noun.

An example sentence could be where I click a button to delete a bunch of these records, and need to pop up a confirmation warning first:

"Do you really want to delete these *whatevers*?"

I'd really rather not have to say "Do you really want to delete these incomes and expenses?" or whatever.

It doesn't *have* to be one word.  eg. another question asked for a hypernym for anywhere that serves food (restaurant, cafe, fast-food place, etc.).  If that's what I was looking for here, then "eating establishment" might be ok.  But if more than one word, it can't just be a string of all the words I'm trying to find the hypernym for (incomes, expenses, etc.).

Comment: they are all ledger line-Items

Comment: @Jim Thanks.  So I read up on ledgers and what they are.  From what I can tell, in accounting, isn't a ledger line-item simply an account?  Or is there some difference?  Might "account"  be the word I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 2):

I would call these things your ***finances***.  Consider definition 1.2 from the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[finance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/finance)***
>
> **noun**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. The management of large amounts of money, especially by governments or large companies.
>
>    *[as modifier] ‘the firm's finance department’*
>
>    1.1 Monetary support for an enterprise.
>
>    *‘the clearing banks are important sources of finance’*
>
>    1.2 finances The monetary resources and affairs of a state, organization, or person.
>
>    *‘the club's finances are stretched to the limit’*

So all of your expenses and income comprise your ***finances***.

Comment: Hmm... interesting, but I think "finance" is too generic a term here.  Almost everything in the entire application could be referred to as finances.  I'd prefer something a little more specific.  One other point too:  Ideally I need a countable noun.  a bill, an expense, a salary.  Since there's no such thing as "a finance" it's not a good choice here.  Still, thanks!

Comment: I understand... but I'm not sure there's a single word that encompasses expense items and revenue items.  I think the closest you'll likely get is, as @Jim suggested, _general ledger line items_.

Comment: Also, you might want to edit your question to note that you're looking for a _countable noun_ and add a sample sentence (such as you might write for documentation) showing how the word you're looking for would be used.  Lastly, are you looking for something simply for internal use as a table/variable name or something that users would see (on screen and in documentation)?  If the former, as long as you have adequate technical documentation for future developers/support staff, you could call it anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to summarise “bills & expenses, and sources of income.”: **revenue and expenditure**

> **[revenue](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revenue)**
>   Revenue is money that a company, organization, or government receives from people.
>
> **[expenditure](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expenditure)**
>   Expenditure is the spending of money on something, or the money that is spent on something.

The compound term, *revenue expenditure*, is used in businesses

> **[revenue expenditure](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revenue-expenditure)**
>
> the amount of money spent by a business or organization on general operating costs such as rent, insurance, heating, maintenance etc

Comment: Hmm... Thanks, but it seems by that definition "revenue expenditure" refers to the amount of money, as opposed to the item (the bill, expense, source of salary, etc.) itself...?